# Chromatic number of a graph such that every region is bordered by exactly 3 edges.

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Let $G$ be a planar graph such that every region is bordered by exactly $3$ edges. What are the possible values of $\chi(G)$?

Since it's neither cyclic or complete, I know we can use Brook's theorem
$\chi(G)\leq\triangle(G)$. I think the answer is 3 just by drawing different graphs but not sure how to give a definite proof.

Comment: What about $G=K_4$?

Comment: @bof you're right, I overlooked that. Laars included $K_4$ in their answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since every region of $G$ is a triangle, then $3\le\chi(G)$.

Since $G$ is planar, then $\chi(G)\le 4$.

Thus $3\le \chi(G) \le 4$.

$K_3$ is an example of a planar graph whose every region is a triangle and has chromatic number of $3$.

$K_4$ is an example of a planar graph whose every region is a triangle and has chromatic number of $4$.